# Como puedo hacer esto, no se como se llama

Tags: html, html5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera hacer esto como de youtube o en otros sitios aparece, quisiera saber el nombre y como lo puedo hacer.

Comment: Quizas buscas por los [menus emergentes o menu de contexto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)?

Comment: se llama así?, como puedo hacerlos

Comment: Dale una mirada a la documentacion y confirma que sea eso lo que buscas para poder darte una respuesta.

Comment: Lo que deseo es que cuando de a esos puntitos, salga una ventana como aparece en la imagen, igual como los puntitos de youtube o de facebook para compartir, etc;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son los llamados **Pop over menus** o **menús contextuales** si tu implementación es para la web puedes usar [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section) o si utilizas nodejs con [Material Components](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/menus/)

[image: Menus material]

> [Lista completa de componentes para nodejs](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/)